# searching for a string in a file

Tags: c++, c

i am new to visual c++ and i am learning oop ,i want ideas or how i can go about this small project i want to create i hope it will help me,i want to write a Class to search the file for a given pattern (eg, content) using visual c++
i want to put a button called search and i want to put an editbox1 where i can enter the path of the where the file is located eg "c:\folder\file1_.txt",then another editbox2 where i can enter words i want to search more like a the find button in word2007,i want it to work in such a way that when i enter the path where the file is located and click open the file should open and when i enter the word and click search it should show the string or word....i need ideas on how i can do this or how to do it your response will be highly appreciated, lets say i want something like this code below....

```
void SearchInFile(const std::string strToSearch, std::string& fileToSearch)
{
////....
}

int main()
{
SearchInFile("abc123", "myfile.txt");
}
```

Comment: This is an awfully broad question. Are you looking with help on how to develop the GUI, the string searching, the file handling, all of the above?

Comment: [This might point you in the right direction...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531890/function-of-searching-a-string-from-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing something from scratch to do this, you might be interested in the built-in `std::string` method `find`. You can read about it [here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)